# Java: Deep Copy Constructor

Tags: java, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I wanted to check if this a deep copy constructor I have created.

```
private int redPixel;
private int greenPixel;
private int bluePixel;

public Pixel(Pixel other)
{
  this.redPixel = other.redPixel;
  this.greenPixel = other.greenPixel;
  this.bluePixel = other.bluePixel;
}
```

Comment: See [Chandra's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834683/438154) answer about what a deep copy is.

Comment: What makes you think this is not a *deep copy*?

Comment: @CommuSoft because from what I understand that this is a shallow copy but I'm trying to create a deep copy without using Serialization and this is where my confusion stems from.

Comment: All primitive types (`int`,`long`,`boolean`,`float`,...), *copy* the value. All other values copy the reference (and thus must be cloned as well). Since in this case, you are only dealing with `int`s, it's a deep copy.